# 3-column layout with non-scrolling fluid-width sidebars (jsFiddle)

Tags: css, fluid-layout

I am looking to create a three-column layout where the left column is a fixed width and the middle and right columns are each 50% of the remaining width. I also want the left and right columns to be non-scolling.

I have achieved partial success in two different ways. [The first](http://jsfiddle.net/UTrrX/) creates fulfils the dynamic columns goal but the right sidebar scolls with the page. I did this with a fixed position left column and another fixed position container which together take up the whole page. I then put the right sidebar in the second container with a width set to 50%.

```
<section id=leftSidebar>
    <p> leftSidebar </p>
</section>

<div id=main>

    <section id=middle>
        <article> middle </article>
        <article> middle </article>
        <article> middle </article>
        <article> middle </article>
        <article> middle </article>
        <article> middle </article>
        <article> middle </article>
        <article> middle </article>
        <article> middle </article>
        <article> middle </article>
        <article> middle </article>
        <article> middle </article>
    </section>

    <section id=rightSidebar>
        <p> rightSidebar </p>
    </section>
</div>
```

Another problem with the above layout is that the content scrolls as a result of `#main {overflow: auto}`. Ideally I would like the content to scroll with the main page.

The [non-scrolling code](http://jsfiddle.net/3tzzP/) is comparatively trivial and simply involves a fixed left and right sidebar with a static width.

I would like to achieve this with just css if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the css `calc() function`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DUR6d/)**

The trick here would be setting both the middle and right cols to 50% of the remaining space.

You could do it like this with calc():

```
#middle, #rightSidebar
{
    width: calc(50% - 40px); /* equals half of 100% - 80px */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example the right column is contained in the main div. Try to close it before opening the column section:

```
<section id=leftSidebar>
    <p> leftSidebar </p>
</section>

<div id=main>

    <section id=middle>
        <article> middle </article>
        <article> middle </article>
        <article> middle </article>
        <article> middle </article>
        <article> middle </article>
        <article> middle </article>
        <article> middle </article>
        <article> middle </article>
        <article> middle </article>
        <article> middle </article>
        <article> middle </article>
        <article> middle </article>
    </section>

</div>

    <section id=rightSidebar>
        <p> rightSidebar </p>
    </section>
```

Comment: CSS doesn't support `width: 50% - 40px;`. #main is a kludge that establishes the total viewport width minus the (static) #leftSidebar width. Then  #middle and #rightSidebar can be set to 50% of that to achieve the effect I want.

Comment: I stand corrected. CSS supports exactly that as danielD noted.